# How do salesforce developers make money?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I'm aware of what salesforce is briefly. I'm entrepreneur and involved in Web development and 3d graphics.

1. Wanted to know how salesforce developers earn. What is the business model?
2. What is the revenue model?
3. Is it still viable business or over saturated (too many players in the game)

Regards,

Comment: Closing this because it's definitely not going to start a constructive conversation. But as a developer working on this platform I can't think of anywhere I'd rather be right now.

Answer (score 13):

Definitely over saturated, don't join this biz.

Comment: Is it about salesforce in particular or complete crm umbrella is saturated

Comment: I would say that all corners of all internet enabled sectors of business have aligned with their primary consultancies. Attempting to invest in tech is a lost cause. You should look to alpaca farming or dandelion farming as a primary trade.

Comment: but if you're really good and want to join the biz hit me up! i got work